# how to parse a boolean argument in a script?

Tags: python-2.7, boolean, command-line-arguments, argparse

The following function and usage examples illustrate exactly what I need with this usage:

`test([{True | False}])`:

```
>>> def test(arg=True):
...     if arg:
...         print "argument is true"
...     else:
...         print "argument is false"
...
>>> test()
argument is true
>>> test(True)
argument is true
>>> test(False)
argument is false
>>> test(1)
argument is true
>>> test(0)
argument is false
>>> test("foo")
argument is true
>>> test("")
argument is false
>>>
```

Now I want exactly the same usage and behaviour but with command-line parsing, i.e. with this usage:

`python test [{True | False}]`

So I am trying to sort out how to do it with something like this:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-arg",
    help="I want the usage to be [{True | False}] (defaults to True)")
arg = parser.parse_args().arg

if arg:
    print "argument is true"
else:
    print "argument is false"
```

But I can't figure it out. I tried all sorts of options and combinations of options among which `action="store_true"`, `default=True`, `choices=[True, False]`, `type=bool` but nothing works as I would like, e.g.:

```
$ python test.py -h
usage: test.py [-h] [-arg ARG]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  -arg ARG    I want the usage to be [{True | False}] (defaults to True)

$ python test.py
argument is true

$ python test.py True
usage: test.py [-h] [-arg ARG]
test.py: error: unrecognized arguments: True

etc.
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The way you set it up, it excepts the argument after -arg, so for example: `python test.py -arg False`. I am not familiar with argparser, but I'd except it to return a string ("False") instead of boolean (False)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find or write a function that parses strings like 'True', 'False'.  For example
http://www.noah.org/wiki/Python_notes#Parse_Boolean_strings

```
def ParseBoolean (b):
    # ...
    if len(b) < 1:
        raise ValueError ('Cannot parse empty string into boolean.')
    b = b[0].lower()
    if b == 't' or b == 'y' or b == '1':
        return True
    if b == 'f' or b == 'n' or b == '0':
        return False
    raise ValueError ('Cannot parse string into boolean.')
```

Think of this as the boolean equivalent of `int()` and `float()`  Then just use it as the argument `type`

```
p.add_argument('foo',type=ParseBoolean)
```

`bool()` doesn't work because the only string it interprets as `False` is `''`.

Answer (score 1):

If you give the parameter a name that starts with "-" it will become a flag parameter. As you can see from the "usage" it excepts it to be called `test.py -arg True`

If you do not want to put `-arg` before the argument itself you should name it just `arg`, so it will become a positional argument.

Reference: http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#name-or-flags

Also it by default will convert the parameters into strings. So `if arg:` does not work. The result would be the same as if you called `if "foo":`.

If you want to be able to type `True` or `False` on the command line you will probably want to keep them as strings and use `if arg == "True"`. Argparse supports boolean arguments, but as far as I know they only support the form: `test.py --arg` results in arg=true, while just `test.py` will result in arg=false

Reference: http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#type

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to varesa who put me on the way I could find this solution:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("arg",
    nargs="?",
    default="True",
    help="I want the usage to be [{True | False}] (defaults to True)")
arg = parser.parse_args().arg

if arg == "True":
    arg = True
elif arg == "False":
    arg = False
else:
    try:
        arg = float(arg)
        if arg == 0.:
            arg = True
        else:
            arg = False
    except:
        if len(arg) > 0:
            arg = True
        else:
            arg = False

if arg:
    print "argument is true"
else:
    print "argument is false"
```

However it seems to me quite complicated. Am I dumb (I am new to Python) or could there be a more simple, more straightforward, more elegant way of doing this? A way that would be close to the very straightforward way that a function handles it, as shown in the original posting.